# Converting hexadecimal to decimal using awk or sed

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, awk

I have a data like this, with comma-separated:

```
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG1,2fe3,c7b1
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG2,2fe3,c7b2
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG3,2fe3,c7b3
03:25:55,Othercauses,N_Pancamukti,N_PancamuktiMG1,2f50,c775
03:25:55,Othercauses,N_Pancamukti,N_PancamuktiMG2,2f50,c776
```

I need to convert last two columns into decimal as below:

```
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG1,12259,51121
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG2,12259,51122
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG3,12259,51123
03:25:55,Othercauses,N_Pancamukti,N_PancamuktiMG1,12112,51061
03:25:55,Othercauses,N_Pancamukti,N_PancamuktiMG2,12112,51062
```

I have already try this one :
cat |nawk -F, '{printf "%d\n" , $1}'

I get nothing but zeroes as output:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Comment: do you have googled already?

Answer (score 3):

With Perl:

```
perl -lpe 's/([^,]*),([^,]*)$/hex($1).",".hex($2)/e' input
```

*Output:*

```
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG1,12259,51121
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG2,12259,51122
18:22:05,OtherOMoperation,BatuAmpar,BatuAmparMG3,12259,51123
03:25:55,Othercauses,N_Pancamukti,N_PancamuktiMG1,12112,51061
03:25:55,Othercauses,N_Pancamukti,N_PancamuktiMG2,12112,51062
```

and similar in gawk:

```
gawk --non-decimal-data -F, '
      BEGIN{OFS=FS}{for(i=5;i<7;i++) $i=sprintf("%d","0x"$i)}1' input
```

Comment: Uhms your awk is way better than the one I proposed, so let's just delete my answer. +1