# converting hexadecimal to decimal from a csv-like txt file

Tags: bash, awk

i am using a bash terminal and i have a .txt file in which i got three columns of Hex numbers separated by a space. I'd like to convert them to decimal numbers. I tried the last command from here [Converting hexadecimal to decimal using awk or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934153/converting-hexadecimal-to-decimal-using-awk-or-sed) but it converts the first column only, put a comma among the columns and put a 0 on the second and third columns.
to have a more clear idea of what i have and what i want:

Input

```
30c8 ffbc 3e80        
30c8 ffbc 3e81
```

Output:

```
12488 65468 16000
12488 65468 16001
```

Comment: i forgot to say i have modified the command i used. I changed the "5" with "1" and the "7" with "4".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach would be to say:

```
$ while read a b c; do echo $((16#$a)) $((16#$b)) $((16#$c)); done < inputfile
12488 65468 16000
12488 65468 16001
```

Comment: This solution is much cleaner than others. Also you can use ``$((0x$a))`` for hex.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As `printf "%d" 0xFF` returns 255 and so on, you can do:

```
$ while read p q r; do printf "%d %d %d\n" 0x$p 0x$q 0x$r; done < input
12488 65468 16000
12488 65468 16001
```

That is, we read 3 variables on each line and we save them as `p`, `q`, `r`. Then we print them with the above form, so that they get printed as decimal.

In case you have another field separator, you can use `IFS` to indicate so:

```
$ cat a
30c8,ffbc,3e80
30c8,ffbc,3e81
$ while IFS=, read p q r; do printf "%d %d %d\n" 0x$p 0x$q 0x$r; done < a
12488 65468 16000
12488 65468 16001
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using another separator, in the original question the separator was "," - you use a blank space.

Try this command instead:

```
gawk --non-decimal-data '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=sprintf("%d","0x"$i)}1' input
```

Comment: The `BEGIN` block doesn't do anything here as `OFS==FS` by default and it's better to use `i<=NF` than hard code the upper limit in the loop.

Comment: That's correct. I was trying to show user2795403 what really is different from the command that he copied. I'm editing my answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`

```
gawk --non-decimal-data '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=sprintf("%d","0x"$i)}1' file
12488 65468 16000
12488 65468 16001
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` you would do:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%d%s",strtonum("0x"$i),(i==NF?RS:FS)}' file
12488 65468 16000
12488 65468 16001
```